# Route voice to bluetooth in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, routes, voice

i want to route the voice to Bluetooth.

below code is my Player.

```
    AudioTrack at;
try {
            minbuffer = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            if (minbuffer < VOICE_SPEECH_SIZE)
                minbuffer = VOICE_SPEECH_SIZE;
            at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minbuffer,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            at.play();

            while (PlayOutblinker == Thread.currentThread()) {
                byte[] tt = vbuff.take();
                at.write(tt, 0, tt.length);
            }
        } finally {
            at.stop();
            at.release();
            at = null;
        }
```

i searched and find below :

```
public static void SetRouteBT(Context context, boolean isRoute) {// TODO
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(isRoute);
}
```

but it does not work.
when i `setBluetoothScoOn(true)` voice does not route but disconnect from speaker and microphone.
where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the function should change to below code :

```
    public static void SetRouteSco(Context context, boolean isRoute) {
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(isRoute);
    if (isRoute)
        mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    else
        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
}
```

and i need below permissions too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```